# Hijacking a WhatsApp session

Tags: malware, whatsapp, trojan

If a device running a WhatsApp account has already be compromised. Can the attacker steal session cookies/encryption keys on the device and establish a persistent connection to receive calls and messages sent to the device?

Would this be possible if the phone has been turned off, but the WhatsApp account has not been registered on another device? Hence, encryption keys and session keys are still valid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by compromised? Gained root, cracked screen lock password or just physical access at locked screen?

Comment: Compromised as in having a trojan installed, or having Google account/iCloud account password stolen and used to take over control of the device. Otherwise, is there any way someone could establish persistent access to the WhatsApp account on the compromised device?

Comment: If the attacker gains root access, he can obtain authentication token of your WhatsApp account but WhatsApp only allows one active device per account so the token will be revoked if two active connections try to submit the same authentication token. Both of you will be thrown back to verify number screen.